# Sending multiple mails in php mail

Tags: php

I am trying to send the multiple mails through my mailer from the below code, But it is showing error

> apache http error occurred.

```
<?php

  require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

  if(isset($_POST['send']))
      {
        $email = $_POST['email'];                    
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $to_id = $_POST['toid'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'mail.domain.com'; 
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = $email;
        $mail->Password = $password;
        $mail->setFrom('info@domain.com', 'Name');
        $mail->addReplyTo('info@domain.com', 'Name');
        // read the list of emails from the file.
       $email_list = file("maillist1.csv");

       // count how many emails there are.
       $total_emails = count($email_list);

       // go through the list and trim off the newline character.
       for ($counter=0; $counter<$total_emails; $counter++) {
       $email_list[$counter] = trim($email_list[$counter]);
       }

      // implode the list in                   
                  require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

                  if(isset($_POST['send']))
                      {
                        $email = $_POST['email'];                    
                        $password = $_POST['password'];
                        $to_id = $_POST['toid'];
                        $message = $_POST['message'];
                        $subject = $_POST['subject'];

                        $mail = new PHPMailer;

                        $mail->isSMTP();
                        $mail->Host = 'mail.domain.com';
                        $mail->Port = 587;
                        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
                        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                        $mail->Username = $email;
                        $mail->Password = $password;
                        $mail->setFrom('info@domain.com', 'Name');
                        $mail->addReplyTo('info@domain.com', 'Name');
                        // read the list of emails from the file.
                       $email_list = file("maillist1.csv");

                       // count how many emails there are.
                       $total_emails = count($email_list);

                       // go through the list and trim off the newline character.
                       for ($counter=0; $counter<$total_emails; $counter++) {
                       $email_list[$counter] = trim($email_list[$counter]);
                       }

                      // implode the list into a single variable, put commas in, apply as $to value.
                      $to = implode(",",$email_list);

                        $mail->addAddress($to);

                        $mail->Subject = $subject;

                        $mail->msgHTML($message);

                 if ( mail($to,$subject,$message) ) {
                    echo "The email has been sent!";
                    } else {
                echo "The email has failed!";
              }


                   }

            ?>to a single variable, put commas in, apply as $to value.
      $to = implode(",",$email_list);

        $mail->addAddress($to);

        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        $mail->msgHTML($message);

 if ( mail($to,$subject,$message) ) {
    echo "The email has been sent!";
 } else {
    echo "The email has failed!";
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: As i see in your code ther is no array of emails there is only one $_POST['email'], no?

Comment: in phpmil official github says: Send emails with multiple TOs, CCs, BCCs and REPLY-TOs
Multipart/alternative emails for mail clients that do not read HTML email

Comment: Little off-topic note. You are sending emails including all the e-mail addresses in the `To:` this will result in everyone seeing each others e-mail address. Might want to change that to `Bcc:`
consider using `$mailer->AddBCC($email, $name);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send mutiple emails in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40169338/how-to-send-mutiple-emails-in-my-code)